# embed error occurs when guild is missing icon?

Tags: discord, discord.js

line of code:

```js
footer: {
text: `${message.guild.name}`,
icon_url: `${message.guild.iconURL({ format: "png", dynamic: true })}`,
}
```

the command shows the name and icon of the server in the footer of the embed and it works perfectly fine unless the guild doesn't have an icon in which case i get the error:

```js
Invalid Form Body
embed.footer.icon_url: Not a well formed URL.
```

any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do an if(){} statement? eg

```
if(!message.guild.iconURL){}
if(message.guild.iconURL){}
```

The "!" means "if not", I might be wrong but that should help you out.

Comment: i've been wondering what the ! means lol so thank you but the error still persists

Comment: Can you please show me how/where did you implement the if statement? I'm not sure you can implement it within Embed messages so I believe you need to have 2 embed, one if ! and one if.

Comment: my whole command is here: https://pastebin.com/0u7bYiZn and i tried putting your if statement below the case, i've only been using js for a few days so if u can please specify how to fix it

Comment: Not sure this will work but give a shot:

**footer: {
                                text: `${message.guild.name}`,
                                icon_url() {
                                    if(message.guild.iconURL){
return `${message.guild.iconURL({ format: "png", dynamic: true })}`
                                } else {'No icon or whatever you need/want'} 
                            }
}**

Comment: Quick one, what is your goal here? Give me the list of what you need, might rewrite your code, I can see you want to show userID, when the user has been added, when was created the account and guild's name/icon as footer. Is that all?

Comment: all the code is right besides the icons. i just don't want the bot to crash whenever the guild doesn't have a picture, i appreciate it but you don't have rewrite the entire code. here's a similar command but this one is just about the current server so there shouldn't be much confusion: https://pastebin.com/FrdD8zeB